# Graphql input mandatory property

Tags: validation, graphql

Is there a possibility to create a GraphQL input with a mandatory input or another.

For example :

```
input ClientInput
{
    name: String!
    token: String!
    email: String!
}
```

I want one of the properties `token` or `email` to be mandatory.
If one of these is provided, the other becomes optional.

Is it possible ?
If not, is there a kind of "workaround" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. One workaround would be to make the two fields aptional, then do manual validation, upon which you can return custom errors.
Another way would be to combine the fields into something like

```
input ClientInput
{
    name: String!
    tokenOrEmail: String!
}
```

By doing this you can make the field mandatory, then do some parsing to determine whether the provided value is token or email
An even better way would be to add another field to provide the authMethod, like so:

```
input ClientInput
{
    name: String!
    authData: String!
    authMethod: AuthMethod!
}
enum AuthMethod {
  EMAIL
  TOKEN
}
```